# Facebook graph api doesn't paginate across all existing feeds, some years and months are completely skipped

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I noticed from a few hours back, that fb seem to suddenly not allow any more pagination pass 500 feed/post of any FB Page.

EDIT: I realised for some pages i can go past 500 feed/post, but the number of feeds returned aren't everything on the fb page!

i.e. we can no longer access from graph api any older (or all) feeds from the FB Page?

There was no such behaviour yesterday.

Can anyone confirm this?

p.s. i tried to adjust the "since" and "until" query to appropriate dates and it doesn't seem to allow me to paginate pass 500 feed too.

Comment: I noticed a similar behaviour on FB pages. The posts of this page just stop before 2017-01-01, even though I see entries in FBs web interface: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/TeamStronach/posts?limit=100&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=created_time,message,story,type,link` (if you click on the "next" url four or five times you will just get an empty array, even though there should be data). Is this what you've got too?

Comment: Yup, same. I got empty arrays too. When did that happened to you?

Comment: I noticed it yesterday. A month ago I requested the same data and back then I got a flawless timeline. Also, I can see the posts in the web interface. On other pages I saw that a year or even several years of posts are missing. One page had six years in posts missing... Did you see that behavior on multiple pages or only on one?

Comment: Same here, there are pages with HUGE gaps, several years in total. Some just stop after a few months.

It happened across all pages i'm looking at right now. You have any idea how to approach of solve this?

Comment: I have no idea. I also posted a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43697759/facebook-graph-api-years-of-public-page-posts-missing-that-are-visible-in-the-w) before I was sure that your problem is the same as mine. No response yet...

Comment: I sent them a message yesterday. Have never done that before, not even sure if they are going to read it... From what I see nothing has changed yet.

Comment: Yup, tested today too. Nothing  changed.  Please update here again if fb says anything!! Thanks for taking the time to email them too! :))

Comment: I think I found the solution: it seems like the API is screwing up hidden posts. If I add the parameter "include_hidden=True" in the query I get all posts! Interestingly, those posts don't seem to be hidden. The "is_hidden" field of the posts is still false, even though I can only get them when I include the hidden ones... Does that work for you too?

Comment: Hey, thats a great solution!! I think i got most of the post by setting "include_hidden=True"! Thanks man!

I still have some posts that are missing though, but its minor. Are you sure you got everything?

Comment: Hey, its a facebook bug. I has been fixed already. I have confirmed it. It is working properly without setting include_hidden. Thanks for commenting in my post and providing guidance @Arkady

Answer (score 1):

Its a facebook bug and it has been resolved backend by the fb developers.

Comment: Right, I also just double-checked it. Everything seems to work now as expected. Here is also a link to FB's response: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2297783020445879/