# Facebook graph api: years of public page posts missing that are visible in the web interface

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

All of a sudden posts on certain public pages seem to be missing when I try to access them with the Facebook Graph API. I know that they exist, I can see them in the web interface. Besides, I have downloaded them a couple of weeks ago.

If you use the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/) and try out this query:

```
TeamStronach/posts?limit=50
```

you will get the posts of the page. If you jump back a couple of times (by clicking the link in the next field of the JSON result at the bottom) you will see that the posts end with 2017-01-01. All posts before that date do not exists, even though they are visible in the web interface. It's a couple of years that are missing here.

I encountered a similar behaviour with this page:

```
Sozialdemokratie/posts?limit=50
```

The entire year 2016 is missing! There is a jump directly from 2017-01-01 to 2015-12-31.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a facebook bug.
it's fixed today.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2297783020445879/

Answer (score 0):

look at changelog. 
backdated_time of posts is not within since and until time range.

[image]